# Javascript's bitwise operators optimization?

Tags: javascript, binary

Javascript ( along with other languages ) won't evaluate :

- The `right` side here : `imTrue || imFalse`
- The `right` side here : `imFalse && imTrue`
  etc...

But does those rules are also applies with **bitwise ** operations ?  ( couldn't find any mdn info)

e.g.

- 1|1 ( would the right side be evaluated here ? )
- 0&1 ( would the right side be evaluated here ? )

Comment: Just test it: `function one(){ console.log('one'); return 1; }
console.log( 1|one() );
console.log( 0&one() );`

Comment: @Sirko Yes I have **already** made a test like you said , but didn't know if it's browser specific optimization or a general rule.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Compilers can only do optimizations if they guarantee that the result of the code will not change. This is true for boolean `||`, because once you get one `true`, the expression can never be false. The same isn't true for bitwise or (`|`), because it doesn't work with just true / false, but a whole set of bits.

Comment: @Matt yup . edited. tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right side in the *logical* operators you show isn't computed because they're [**short circuit operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

There's no such thing for bitwise operators (yes, they're not just boolean operators, they're bitwise operators, which quite changes the problem).

A simple demonstration :

```
0 & (function(){ return console.log('evaluated'),1 })();
```

The main reason for short circuit operator isn't performance, it's the ability to avoid errors in such evaluations :

```
if (a && a.pretty) ...
```

It's hard to come with the need for short circuit protection when doing bitwise operations.

Note also that the weak typing of javascript makes it hard to evaluate when you don't need the right side. Luaan gives a good example : `1|2`.

Comment: So ,   `1|1` both operators would be evaluated ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes. They have to be, because you can do eg. `1 | 2`. How would you tell the result of that operation with just the first operand? Why can't you short-circuit `1 + 1`? :)

Comment: @Luaan yes.... I guess I was dealing with too much bool opearations yesterday. indeed 1|2 helps :-)